# Updating MAMP Pro from 5.7 > 6.1 "site can't be reached"

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

My existing websites (all WordPress) cannot be loaded, no matter which ports I try. So I created a new host and installed WordPress - `testwp` - I installed an SSL certificate. When opening the host in the browser it tries to connect to https://testwp:8890 which is correct, but I get the message "site can't be reached".

I've been going round in circles with this for a whole day now, any help is much appreciated.

MySQL error log reports

```
2020-11-13T00:41:28.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2020-11-13T00:41:28.300631Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.302593Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 32951 ...
2020-11-13T00:41:28.317147Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2020-11-13T00:41:28.324278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-11-13T00:41:28.324316Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-13T00:41:28.324329Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-11-13T00:41:28.324358Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-13T00:41:28.324404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2020-11-13T00:41:28.326134Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-13T00:41:28.328643Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-11-13T00:41:28.330673Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-11-13T00:41:28.343405Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-13T00:41:28.368168Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.695588Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-13T00:41:28.695756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-13T00:41:28.715929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.717355Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.717385Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.717756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-11-13T00:41:28.772940Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 3029357528
2020-11-13T00:41:28.773004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
2020-11-13T00:41:28.773417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-13T00:41:28.780109Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.814499Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201113  0:41:28
2020-11-13T00:41:28.842180Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.842217Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.851648Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.852747Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.854560Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/Applications/MAMP/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-11-13T00:41:28.891010Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2020-11-13T00:41:28.961879Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-11-13T00:41:28.962144Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: When can you Skype and Screen Share?  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: Any changes since you posted??